# Firebase database stopped working after the null safety update

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Errors like these

/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_database-6.1.0/lib/src/firebase_database.dart:14:26: Error: The parameter 'app' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'FirebaseApp', but the implicit default value is 'null'.

- 'FirebaseApp' is from 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.0.1/lib/firebase_core.dart').
  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

Comment: run--> flutter pub outdated in your application terminal and set the latest version to flutter firebase and core package.

Comment: You couldn't able to set the null to FirebaseApp because it non-nullable api

Comment: @BalasubramaniSundaram That's my point I can't do anything about it It's not my code it's what the flutter team has written for their database plugin. I haven't changed anything